# Python Project Structure - multiple files and modules

Tags: python, scope, architecture, python-import, python-module

I was used to PHP where a global variable will be available on the whole project, and including/requiring a PHP file is pretty much just like 'injecting' it's code lines on that spot: the whole thing would be 'seen' as a single file, and all vars would be instinctively acessed.

Python works in a different way and I'd like to know good practices in order to make a large project more manageable by splitting it into files...

So lets say I have a file called configs.py that's something like:

```
FRAME_DURATION = int(1000 / 25)
SCREEN_SIZE = 500

LIGHT_GREY  = (190,190,190)
RED = (255,0,0)
GREEN = (0,255,0)
YELLOW = (255,255,0)
#etc...
```

Then, on the Main.py file I could do something like:

```
import pygame
from configs import *

pygame.init()   
SCREEN = pygame.display.set_mode((SCREEN_SIZE, SCREEN_SIZE),1)
SCREEN.fill(LIGHT_GREY)

run = True
while run:
    pygame.time.delay(FRAME_DURATION )

    #HERE I'M SUPPOSED TO CHECK THE KEYBOARD AND MOUSE EVENTS

    pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit()
```

And this work just fine since we're handling only variables. But if i want to make the event listener into another separate file I run into some 'troubles'. Let's say I want a file with all my functions. I'll name it actions.py and it contains the following function:

```
def checkEvents():
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                run = False
            if event.key == pygame.K_r:
                pass
```

If I want to be able to call the checkEvents() function inside the main.py file I get a NameError sinceit doesn't recognizes pygame module inside the actions.py file.

I can't seem to make it work: if i import it on both files (which i know is sup-optimal), the game launches but keys and exit key don't do nothing. I guess the checkEvents() function is listening to another instance of pygame?

Anyway, I'd like to know if there's a way to make modules 'globally available'... Importing it once on main file and using it on the whole project, including inside other imported custom modules?

The final result should look something like this:

```
import pygame
from configs import *
import actions

pygame.init()   
SCREEN = pygame.display.set_mode((SCREEN_SIZE, SCREEN_SIZE),1)
SCREEN.fill(LIGHT_GREY)

run = True
while run:
    pygame.time.delay(FRAME_DURATION )

    actions.checkEvents()

    pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: You'll need to either pass the initialized `pygame` instance to `checkEvents(pygame)` or alternatively create a separate module - e.g. `game.py` that holds the `pygame` instance and then import that in both `main.py` and `actions.py`.

Comment: i tried passing pygame and also the run variable with no success, i still have to terminate the program via task manager.

also tried storing the 'pygame.init()' into a variable and passing it to the checkEvents() function, but it throws an AttributeError inside the actions.py file saying " 'tuple' object has no attribute 'event' "

Comment: what shoul'd be the right way to pass the initialized pygame to checkEvents()? could you give me a syntax example? 

Also, i dont like the idea of importing something twice... I import game.py inside main, also import it inside actions.py and then import actions.py inside main? 
wouldn't that hinder performance if done to multiple modules? 
also, it doesnt seem so intuitive to make the maintenance...

Comment: you need only `import pygame` in `actions.py`

Comment: i tried it. import pygame, and then later, i call `actions.checkEvents(pygame)`
i even tried `actions.checkEvents(pygame, run)`
to see if it was not changing the run variable because scope issues

Comment: don't send `pygame` as argument - use your old code - `actions.checkEvents()`

Comment: oh, sorry, furas, i misread your first comment.

Importing pygame on both modules doesnt work (the app runs but i keys dont do nothing). still having to close it by task manager, and printing tests also fail

Comment: you have to send `return run` to main code - because `run` in `checkEvent` is local variable and has nothing to do with `run` which you use in main code.

Answer (score 1):

You have to only `import pygame` in `actions.py`

Other problem is `run` which you have to return from `checkEvents()`

```
import pygame 

def checkEvents():
    run = True # local variable with default value before all tests

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False # set local variable

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                run = False # set local variable
            if event.key == pygame.K_r:
                pass

    return run # return local value to main code
```

And then you get `run` in `main.py`

```
import pygame
from configs import *
import actions

pygame.init()   
SCREEN = pygame.display.set_mode((SCREEN_SIZE, SCREEN_SIZE),1)
SCREEN.fill(LIGHT_GREY)

run = True
while run:
    pygame.time.delay(FRAME_DURATION )

    run = actions.checkEvents() # get result from function and assign to `run`

    pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: ok, that solves this specific problem, but there must be a better way...

if i want to interact with `SCREEN` inside checkEvents(), let's say darkening or lightening it's fill collor. do i need to pass it and then return it again?

we are not changing scopes, we are passing the variables and then returning them... that can be a problem if my checkEvents() function needs to change a different variable for each key pressed...

Comment: also, isn't sub-optimal importing a module twice? wont it take exponentially longer as i make this architecture more and more complex?

Comment: you need `pygame` in `actions.py` so import it - it is natural method - and don't waste time for "sub-optimal" and "exponentially" because you will never see this problem.

Comment: if you need `SCREEN` in `checkEvents()` then send it as argument - `run = actions.checkEvents(SCREEN)` and `def checkEvents(SCREEN):` And you don't have to send it back - it is not simple variable which change value but class instance and it change vlaues of its properties.

Comment: i see... so, there's absolutely no way of making a variable or a func/method globally accessible between two imported modules?
any way, i appreciate your help, thanks very much